# Failed to restrict google Api key for android app

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to restrict the access of my google cloud API key for my android app, but I always get the below message when I tried to use google maps API.

**"This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address {myIp}, with empty referer"**

I followed [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys?hl=en&visit_id=636976716993216288-4203193488&rd=1)

## some hints:

```
manifest package name: sa.com.myapp
applicationId in gradle: com.myapp
and debug flavour has the suffix like this
debug {
 applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
}
```

what do you think the proper package name value for both debug and release?

Comment: Facing the same issue, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your SHA1 is also on the console with your package name. You get this from the keystore used to sign each version; release & debug. Follow the [Restrict the API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key) section.

Debug pacakge name: `com.myapp.debug`

Release package name: `com.myapp`

Comment: i already got the sha1 for both release and debug and used the  package names you provided, but the problem still exist

Comment: Definitely the right keystores with correct passwords etc? Even if they are incorrect they still return SHA1s

Comment: without the restriction, everything is ok and the map locations are loaded using my keystore, but when i restrict the access for the andorid form the console, the map requests gives the above message. should i add some extra headers  for the requests!

Comment: Yes I understand the issue. I can't see a problem with your package name. My only other suggestion is like I mentioned. You are using an incorrect alias and password for the keystore when getting your SHA1 certificate.

Comment: for the sha generation, i generated it using the gradle singing report utility inside the android studio ide. also using the keytool from the terminal and both ways are matched!

Comment: in my case ,the package name in manifest is different than the applicationId in gradle. is this a problem?

Comment: My debug version map was working but release version map was not working. Provided link did the trick. As per documentation "If you're using Play App Signing instead, you must go to the app signing page on the Play Console to get your certificate fingerprint." this solved my problem. Because I was creating SHA-1 certificate by keytool but my app was using Google play signing.
N.B. App siging key can be found in Setup > App Integrity > App Signing tab from Google Play Store.